# Building a QR code scanning app on Android

Tags: android, qr-code, reader

I want to build a QR code scanner app, what can I use? And can anyone teach or send me a link/s on how to build it?

Comment: Great library for generating and reading QR codes https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded

Comment: Check out this https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes from firebase

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to create a QR code scanner app at work and I used **Zxing library (zebra crossing)**. It is very easy to use and you can set the QR code scanner in a couple of minutes. I helped myself with this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe7F4Jx7rwo

I hope this helps you!